# Name Picture with python - specific pattern

Tags: python-3.x, loops, rename, enumerate, natsort

I want to change the name of the pictures I took. It should look like this after:

- 20200701_Foto_1.1.jpg
- 20200701_Foto_1.2.jpg
- 20200701_Foto_1.3.jpg
- 20200701_Foto_PB1.jpg
- 20200701_Foto_2.1.jpg
- 20200701_Foto_2.2.jpg
- 20200701_Foto_2.3.jpg
- 20200701_Foto_PB2.jpg
- ...

The code written down here does not work and I don't know how to write it differently. Does someone of you have an idea ? :-)

Looking forward reading you!

```
import os
from natsort import natsorted

datum = 20200701
os.chdir('/Users/Aka/Desktop/'+datum+'_Fotos_rawdata Kopie')
for i in enumerate(natsorted(os.listdir('/Users/Aka/Desktop/'+datum+'_Fotos_rawdata Kopie'))):
    for j in (1,4):
        if j ==1 or j==2 or j==3:
            os.rename(datum+"_Foto_",i+"."+j,".jpg")
        if j ==4:
            os.rename(datum+"_Foto_PB",i,".jpg")
```

Comment: Any console errors? Because, first of all, you are trying to add `int` to string and it results in `TypeError`

Comment: What specifically is not working? Lots of things can go wrong. Is it completing but not giving the results you expect, or is it failing with an error? In either case, please provide the details describing how you know it is not working, and what you expect instead.